# Write lambda expression for data filter with null and empty value

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I want to filter the data with null and empty value. I have written below code snippet. please help me on it.

```cs
string ContainsFieldType = ......;
List<Field> entityFields = .......;

var fieldListValue = entityFields
    .Where(x => x.FieldType.Id.Contains(ContainsFieldType))
    .ToList()
    .Select(y => y.Data.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You do not need the .ToList().Select in the middle.  Just use .Select

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a new condition to your code

```
var fieldListValue = entityFields
    .Where(x => x.FieldType.Id.Contains(ContainsFieldType) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Data))
    .ToList();
```

Example Data

```
class Field
{
    public FieldType FieldType { set; get; }
    public string Data { set; get; }
}

public class FieldType
{  public string Id { set; get; }
}

List<Field> entityFields = new List<Field>();
entityFields.Add(new Field() { Data = "ss", FieldType = new FieldType() { Id = "1" } });

entityFields.Add(new Field() { Data = "", FieldType = new FieldType() { Id = "1" } });
entityFields.Add(new Field() { Data = null, FieldType = new FieldType() { Id = "1" } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what you are trying to achieve here. You need to give more details.

If my assumption is correct then you need to do something like that:

```
var fieldListValue = entityFields
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x?.FieldType?.Id) && x.FieldType.Id.Contains(ContainsFieldType))
    .Select(y => y.Data.ToString())
    .ToList();
```